# Prepare 4 lists from existing lists based on the value of one of the list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to prepare 2 lists based on the elements of one list.

```
>>> a = ['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig']
>>> b = ['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8', '1/6/1', '1/6/2']
```

I need to map elements of list `a` to elements of list `b`, and make a new list from list `b` for which list b has `ether1000`.

So this should be the resultant lists:

```
res1 = ['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']
res2 = ['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8']
res3 = ['ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig']
res4 = ['1/6/1', '1/6/2']
```

I tried doing zip of 2 lists:

```
>>> zip(a, b)
[('ether1000', '1/11/5'), ('ether1000', '1/11/6'), ('ether1000', '1/11/7'), ('ether1000', '1/11/8'), ('ether100Gig', '1/6/1'), ('ether100Gig', '1/6/2')]

>>> c = zip(a,b)
>>> for i in c:
...  if 'ether1000' in i:
...   d.append[i(1)]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

But from this, I am not sure how I can extract elements with `ether1000` value and make 2 lists as above. It will be good if someone can give me a hint on how to resolve this?

Editing based on answers:

I got these 2 lists, is there anyway I can make other two lists res3 and res4?

```
>>> [el[0] for el in c if 'ether1000' in el]
['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']

>>> [i[1] for i in zip(a,b) if 'ether1000' in i]
['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8']
```

Comment: ports with 'ether1000' should go in one list and whatever is the length of ports list, same length should be of list with 'ether1000' elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the line `d.append[i(1)]`, instead you should be using:

```
#       v  `(..)` for function call 
d.append(i[1])
#         ^ for fetching the index
# Since you want to access the index, you need to use `i[1]`
```

Here's the example for your input:

```
>>> a = ['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig']
>>> b = ['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8', '1/6/1', '1/6/2']

>>> res1, res2, res3, res4 = [], [], [], []
>>> for i, j in zip(a, b):
...     if i == 'ether1000':
...         res1.append(i)
...         res2.append(j)
...     else:
...         res3.append(i)
...         res4.append(j)
...
>>> res1
['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']
>>> res2
['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8']
>>> res3
['ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig']
>>> res4
['1/6/1', '1/6/2']
```

---

However you may simplify your answer via using *list comprehension* with `zip`as:

```
>>> res1, res2 = zip(* [i for i in zip(a,b) if 'ether1000' in i[0]])
>>> res1
('ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000')
>>> res2
('1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8')
# These are the `tuple` values instead of `list` but I don't think it matters for you

>>> res3, res4 = zip(* [i for i in zip(a,b) if 'ether1000' not in i[0]])
>>> res3
('ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig')
>>> res4
('1/6/1', '1/6/2')
```

But in the list comprehension approach, you'll be iterating your initial list twice. I'll suggest to use the first approach.

Comment: Is there any better way to avoid all these looping and new list append operations?

Comment: @Sweety Yup: `d = [el[1] for el in c if 'ether1000' in el]`.

Comment: It should be `.append()` with parentheses not brackets

Comment: @AnthonyPham ohh yes, nice catch!

Comment: @ChristianDean Yup, I added the similar list comprehension to the answer as requested by Sweety.

Comment: `>>> d = [el[0] for el in c if 'ether1000' in el]
>>> d
['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']`
I need port list which have ether1000 in mapped list c.

Comment: what to do you mean by **port list**? Can you give the sample of desired result?

Comment: res1, res2, res3, res4 -> these are result lists which are desired.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the index of the tuple *and* calling `.append()` via:

```
d.append(i[1])
```

You got your brackets and parentheses mixed up. `.append()` has parentheses since it's a function and when accessing an item in a list or tuple, use brackets (i.e `i[index]`). Your error was basically telling you that a tuple is not a function. You can use list comprehension as well to help:

```
[i[1] for i in zip(a,b) if 'ether1000' in i]
```

Thanks to @ChristianDean

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary containing all of the matching items from list `b` (keyed on the item).  Then just get the relevant item and assign it to your variable.  The first list is easy to create (e.g. ['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']), as it is just [key] * len(result[key]).

The variable `result` is created using a dictionary comprehension, and each value in this dictionary is created using a conditional list comprehension.

Although you need to pass through the dictionary for each unique item, it is probably more efficient than looping once and appending to multiple lists.  If you have a high number of unique items relative to the size of the list, however, you may be better of using a different approach (see **Option 2**)

**Option 1**

```
result = {unique_item: [val for item, val in zip(a, b) if item == unique_item]
          for unique_item in set(a)}

res2 = result['ether1000']
res1 = ['ether1000'] * len(res2)

>>> res1
['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000']

>>> res2
['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8']
```

**Option 2**

You can use `defaultdict` to create a dictionary of empty lists.  Then enumerate through list `a` and add the corresponding item from list `b` to the dictionary keyed on the item.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for n, item in enumerate(a):
    result[item].append(b[n])
```

Then continue as above to get `res1` and `res2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by -

```
a = ['ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether1000', 'ether100Gig', 'ether100Gig']
b = ['1/11/5', '1/11/6', '1/11/7', '1/11/8', '1/6/1', '1/6/2']
a_uniq = list(set(a))

results = []

for each in a_uniq:
    ind = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == each]
    _a = [a[i] for i in ind]
    _b = [b[i] for i in ind]
    results.append([_a,_b])
```

Each element in the `results` will be a list of two lists which will have the values of a and corresponding elements from b